# Is there a function to add WOE, calculated on Training data, to the whole data set? (python)

Tags: python, training-data

I am working on some python code to predict Default rate of loans handed out by a bank.

I have calculated the WOE and information value (IV) on the training set 
(using the following code: https://github.com/Sundar0989/WOE-and-IV/blob/master/WOE_IV.ipynb?fbclid=IwAR1MvEfyGsdyTre0uPJC5WRl91dfue_t0vH5qJezwm2mAg6sjHZJg9MyDYo).

We have also concluded 2 high cardinality variables. We don't know however how to add these WOE scores to the whole set. How do we tackle this problem? How can we go further to use WOE to predict the target variable?

code:

```
import os 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy, pylab
```

## Reading the data received from bank, feature selection part 1, splitting up whole set (Training) into training set: indices_traintrain, validation set: indices_val and test set: indices_test (70/30 split training and validation set - test set and 70/30 split training - validation)

```
Training =
pd.read_excel('/Users/enjo/Documents/Master/DM/Data_DSC2019_STUDENTS/DSC2019_Training.xlsx', na_values=np.nan)  

Status = Training.iloc[:,-1]
Data = Training.iloc[:,0:45]

Data_missing = Data.isna()
Data_missing = Data_missing.sum()
print(Data_missing/len(Data))

"""
drop variables with more than 80% missing
"""

Drop = ['FREE_CASH_FLOW_AMT', 
 'A2_MTHS_FIRST_PCX_COREPROF_CNT', 'A2_MONTHS_IN_BELGIUM_CNT', 'A2_MTHS_SNC_FIRST_COREPROF_CNT', 'MONTHS_SINCE_LAST_REFUSAL_CNT']  

DroppedTraining = Training.copy()
for element in Drop:
    DroppedTraining.drop(element, axis=1,inplace=True)

import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import preprocessing
Data_preprocessed=[] #contains preprocessed data
from Preprocessing_continuous import Preprocessing_continuous #import function for preprocessing
from Preprocessing_discrete import Preprocessing_discrete #import function for preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

indices=np.arange(26962)
indices_train, indices_test  = train_test_split(indices, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
indices_traintrain, indices_val  = train_test_split(indices_train, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

Training['target']= Training['Label_Default'].apply(lambda x:1 if x=='Y' else 0)

Highcardinalityset=[]
Highcardinalityset = Training[['Type', 
                                       'INDUSTRY_CD_3',
                                       'INDUSTRY_CD_4',
                                       'Managing_Sales_Office_Nbr',
                                       'Postal_Code_L',
                                       'Product_Desc',
                                       'CREDIT_TYPE_CD',
                                       'ACCOUNT_PURPOSE_CD',
                                       'A2_MARITAL_STATUS_CD',
                                       'FINANCIAL_PRODUCT_TYPE_CD',
                                       'A2_EMPLOYMENT_STATUS_CD',
                                       'A2_RESIDENT_STATUS_CD', 
                                       'target']]
Highcardinalityset = Highcardinalityset.iloc[indices_traintrain]
```

## function found on github

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.core.algorithms as algos
from pandas import Series
import scipy.stats.stats as stats
import re
import traceback
import string

max_bin = 20
force_bin = 3

# define a binning function
def mono_bin(Y, X, n = max_bin):

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": X, "Y": Y})
    justmiss = df1[['X','Y']][df1.X.isnull()]
    notmiss = df1[['X','Y']][df1.X.notnull()]
    r = 0
    while np.abs(r) < 1:
        try:
            d1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": notmiss.X, "Y": notmiss.Y, "Bucket": pd.qcut(notmiss.X, n)})
            d2 = d1.groupby('Bucket', as_index=True)
            r, p = stats.spearmanr(d2.mean().X, d2.mean().Y)
            n = n - 1 
        except Exception as e:
            n = n - 1

    if len(d2) == 1:
        n = force_bin         
        bins = algos.quantile(notmiss.X, np.linspace(0, 1, n))
        if len(np.unique(bins)) == 2:
            bins = np.insert(bins, 0, 1)
            bins[1] = bins[1]-(bins[1]/2)
        d1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": notmiss.X, "Y": notmiss.Y, "Bucket": pd.cut(notmiss.X, np.unique(bins),include_lowest=True)}) 
        d2 = d1.groupby('Bucket', as_index=True)

    d3 = pd.DataFrame({},index=[])
    d3["MIN_VALUE"] = d2.min().X
    d3["MAX_VALUE"] = d2.max().X
    d3["COUNT"] = d2.count().Y
    d3["EVENT"] = d2.sum().Y
    d3["NONEVENT"] = d2.count().Y - d2.sum().Y
    d3=d3.reset_index(drop=True)

    if len(justmiss.index) > 0:
        d4 = pd.DataFrame({'MIN_VALUE':np.nan},index=[0])
        d4["MAX_VALUE"] = np.nan
        d4["COUNT"] = justmiss.count().Y
        d4["EVENT"] = justmiss.sum().Y
        d4["NONEVENT"] = justmiss.count().Y - justmiss.sum().Y
        d3 = d3.append(d4,ignore_index=True)

    d3["EVENT_RATE"] = d3.EVENT/d3.COUNT
    d3["NON_EVENT_RATE"] = d3.NONEVENT/d3.COUNT
    d3["DIST_EVENT"] = d3.EVENT/d3.sum().EVENT
    d3["DIST_NON_EVENT"] = d3.NONEVENT/d3.sum().NONEVENT
    d3["WOE"] = np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)
    d3["IV"] = (d3.DIST_EVENT-d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)*np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)
    d3["VAR_NAME"] = "VAR"
    d3 = d3[['VAR_NAME','MIN_VALUE', 'MAX_VALUE', 'COUNT', 'EVENT', 'EVENT_RATE', 'NONEVENT', 'NON_EVENT_RATE', 'DIST_EVENT','DIST_NON_EVENT','WOE', 'IV']]       
    d3 = d3.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)
    d3.IV = d3.IV.sum()

    return(d3)

def char_bin(Y, X):

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": X, "Y": Y})
    justmiss = df1[['X','Y']][df1.X.isnull()]
    notmiss = df1[['X','Y']][df1.X.notnull()]    
    df2 = notmiss.groupby('X',as_index=True)

    d3 = pd.DataFrame({},index=[])
    d3["COUNT"] = df2.count().Y
    d3["MIN_VALUE"] = df2.sum().Y.index
    d3["MAX_VALUE"] = d3["MIN_VALUE"]
    d3["EVENT"] = df2.sum().Y
    d3["NONEVENT"] = df2.count().Y - df2.sum().Y

    if len(justmiss.index) > 0:
        d4 = pd.DataFrame({'MIN_VALUE':np.nan},index=[0])
        d4["MAX_VALUE"] = np.nan
        d4["COUNT"] = justmiss.count().Y
        d4["EVENT"] = justmiss.sum().Y
        d4["NONEVENT"] = justmiss.count().Y - justmiss.sum().Y
        d3 = d3.append(d4,ignore_index=True)

    d3["EVENT_RATE"] = d3.EVENT/d3.COUNT
    d3["NON_EVENT_RATE"] = d3.NONEVENT/d3.COUNT
    d3["DIST_EVENT"] = d3.EVENT/d3.sum().EVENT
    d3["DIST_NON_EVENT"] = d3.NONEVENT/d3.sum().NONEVENT
    d3["WOE"] = np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)
    d3["IV"] = (d3.DIST_EVENT-d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)*np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)
    d3["VAR_NAME"] = "VAR"
    d3 = d3[['VAR_NAME','MIN_VALUE', 'MAX_VALUE', 'COUNT', 'EVENT', 'EVENT_RATE', 'NONEVENT', 'NON_EVENT_RATE', 'DIST_EVENT','DIST_NON_EVENT','WOE', 'IV']]      
    d3 = d3.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)
    d3.IV = d3.IV.sum()
    d3 = d3.reset_index(drop=True)

    return(d3)

def data_vars(df1, target):

    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    filename, lineno, function_name, code = stack[-2]
    vars_name = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\).*$').search(code).groups()[0]
    final = (re.findall(r"[\w']+", vars_name))[-1]

    x = df1.dtypes.index
    count = -1

    for i in x:
        if i.upper() not in (final.upper()):
            if np.issubdtype(df1[i], np.number) and len(Series.unique(df1[i])) > 2:
                conv = mono_bin(target, df1[i])
                conv["VAR_NAME"] = i
                count = count + 1
            else:
                conv = char_bin(target, df1[i])
                conv["VAR_NAME"] = i            
                count = count + 1

            if count == 0:
                iv_df = conv
            else:
                iv_df = iv_df.append(conv,ignore_index=True)

    iv = pd.DataFrame({'IV':iv_df.groupby('VAR_NAME').IV.max()})
    iv = iv.reset_index()
    return(iv_df,iv)

final_iv, IV = data_vars(Highcardinalityset,Highcardinalityset.target)
```

## final_iv

```
IV.sort_values('IV')

IV.to_csv('test.csv')

transform_vars_list = Highcardinalityset.columns.difference(['target'])
transform_prefix = 'new_' # leave this value blank if you need replace the original column values

transform_vars_list

for var in transform_vars_list:
    small_df = final_iv[final_iv['VAR_NAME'] == var]
    transform_dict = dict(zip(small_df.MAX_VALUE.astype(str),small_df.WOE.astype(str)))    
    replace_cmd = ''
    replace_cmd1 = ''
    for i in sorted(transform_dict.items()):        
        replace_cmd = replace_cmd + str(i[1]) + str(' if x <= ') + str(i[0]) + ' else '
        replace_cmd1 = replace_cmd1 + str(i[1]) + str(' if x == "') + str(i[0]) + '" else '
    replace_cmd = replace_cmd + '0'
    replace_cmd1 = replace_cmd1 + '0'
    if replace_cmd != '0':
        try:
            Highcardinalityset[transform_prefix + var] = Highcardinalityset[var].apply(lambda x: eval(replace_cmd))
        except:
            Highcardinalityset[transform_prefix + var] = Highcardinalityset[var].apply(lambda x: eval(replace_cmd1))

Highcardinalityset['Postal_Code_L'].value_counts()
Highcardinalityset['new_Postal_Code_L'].value_counts()

Highcardinalityset['Managing_Sales_Office_Nbr'].value_counts()
Highcardinalityset['new_Managing_Sales_Office_Nbr'].value_counts()
```

**Nice to see when high WOE: interesting for that postal code: high risk for default!**

```
Highcardinalityset.to_excel("Highcardinalitysettraintrain.xlsx")

TrainingWOE = DroppedTraining[['Managing_Sales_Office_Nbr', "Postal_Code_L"]]
TrainingWOE["Postal_Code_L_WOE"]=Highcardinalityset[["new_Postal_Code_L"]]
TrainingWOE["Managing_Sales_Office_Nbr_WOE"]=Highcardinalityset[["new_Managing_Sales_Office_Nbr"]]
```

## drop variables that are not relevant because of low IV value

```
Drop = ["ACCOUNT_PURPOSE_CD", "A2_MARITAL_STATUS_CD", "A2_EMPLOYMENT_STATUS_CD", "A2_RESIDENT_STATUS_CD",
                  "INDUSTRY_CD_3", "INDUSTRY_CD_4","Type"]
DroppedTrainingAfterIVcalc = DroppedTraining.copy()
for element in Drop:
    DroppedTrainingAfterIVcalc.drop(element, axis=1,inplace=True)
```

## preprocess remaining (44-5 (because of too many missing) - 7 (because of low iv) + 1 (target variable added))

Comment: Hi @EnjoFaes, welcome to Stackoverflow. We generally ask that you include the relevant code in your post, that way we get a nice archive of the full question even if the repo disappears later on. Could you take the concise relevant code from your github example and post it here?

Comment: You might be more interested in asking this question is stats exchange or maybe data science given the nature of the problem you are facing.

Comment: someone an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for asking this question. Here is the code to do the required transformation which is shown in the notebook as well.

```
transform_vars_list = df.columns.difference(['target'])
transform_prefix = 'new_' # leave this value blank to replace the original column

#apply transformations
for var in transform_vars_list:
    small_df = final_iv[final_iv['VAR_NAME'] == var]
    transform_dict = dict(zip(small_df.MAX_VALUE,small_df.WOE))
    replace_cmd = ''
    replace_cmd1 = ''
    for i in sorted(transform_dict.items()):
        replace_cmd = replace_cmd + str(i[1]) + str(' if x <= ') + str(i[0]) + ' else '
        replace_cmd1 = replace_cmd1 + str(i[1]) + str(' if x == "') + str(i[0]) + '" else '
    replace_cmd = replace_cmd + '0'
    replace_cmd1 = replace_cmd1 + '0'
    if replace_cmd != '0':
        try:
            df[transform_prefix + var] = df[var].apply(lambda x: eval(replace_cmd))
        except:
            df[transform_prefix + var] = df[var].apply(lambda x: eval(replace_cmd1))
```

In addition, there is a package Xverse which does the same. Please refer to it here - https://github.com/Sundar0989/XuniVerse